# How can I count the number of views everytime we make a request to a specific id in db?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

How can I count the views of a specific post on my db when it is requested by the user(every user just make one view)?

```
const CommenTs = new Schema({
    iduser: {
        type: String,

      },
    picuser: {
         type: String,
      },
    description:{
        type: String,
        maxlength:[150,'The Username must be maximum 150 charecters'],

    },
    likescount:{
        type:Number

    },
    linkvoice:{
        type:Schema.Types.Mixed

    }
});

const NEWSModel = new Schema({
viewsCount:{
    type:Number

},
publishedBy:{
    type:String,
    required:true,

},
PublisherPic:{
    type: String,

},
PublishedData:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now

},
Subject:{
    type:String,
    required:true

},
Description:{
    type:String,
    required:true

},
Pics:{
    type:Array

},
Tags:{
    type:Array

},
LikesCount:{
    type:Number

},
DislikeCount:{
    type:Number

},
CommentsCount:{
    type:Number

},
Comments:CommenTs

});
```

Every time I make a request to see a specific news, every user can make only one view, I mean if a user views that for a few times it just counts one, I want to store that number into my db, and when a req by a new user made increment it.

Comment: In node, you know the user and the view he is requesting correct? If so, that should be enough to increment a counter in your db

Comment: im really new to node.js i dont know the user, how can i handle the authentication  for a user? and dont know the view though, @Geert-Jan

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new field on your news model called, let's say, viewedBy it should be an array of objects and every object will be a reference to a user as follows:

```
viewedBy:[{Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User"}]
```

Every time a user views a news, you'll need to add this user to the news viewedBy field we just created above. That's the logic db will need to know that specific news was saw for that particular user, then the quantity of views will be just the length of viewedBy array.
Hope it could helps.